# Where to get UK Mobile phone to email gateway

Tags: email, sms, gateway

What I need is:
- 3-5 phone numbers in the UK, possibly on different networks
- charge phones by Credit card
- text messages received by these numbers get emailed to me (one by one)
- Needs to work with premium text messages, i.e. the one where you pay as a recipient.

Comment: In more detail, I'm looking for a gateway to test receipt of MT messages that terminate on Uk numbers. This is to do live testing of a UK based message service and MO gateway provider when not in the UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) is one of the most often recommended providers for this kind of service.  They provide a lot of developer support too, with APIs and code examples to cover almost every requirement.

Beware if you intend to shop around though: SMS Gateways are bit of a tricky area - costs, rules and service quality for SMS vary wildly from country to country, and there are a great many small middlemen reselling SMS gateway services, some of which are disreputable spammers.

If you search StackOverflow for SMS you should see a number of similar/overlapping questions have a lot more detail, and discuss the pros and cons of different providers:

- [Receive SMS messages by web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526046/receive-sms-messages-by-web-application)
- [Send and receive SMSs to a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410022/send-and-receive-smss-to-a-php-script)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238579/free-sms-api (beware accepted answer)
- [Receiving a SMS message in a .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388657/receiving-a-sms-message-in-a-net-application)